# How to add the column and than update the column in sql server using procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have created the table called test_exam 
create table test_exam(id int,age int)
than i want through procedure add column called name and update it value.

i have made the procedure

```
create procedure [dbo].[abcd1] @tablename sysname
as
begin
declare @query nvarchar(4000)
declare @name_test varchar(20)
set @query = N'select top 10 * from transorg_DW.dbo.'+@tablename
print @query
alter table test_exam add name varchar(20);
update test_exam set name='shyam' where id=1;

exec sp_executesql 
end
```

its through an error

> invalid column name.

how to rectify this error?

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle? (That code won't run on all of them.)

Comment: sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call it dynamically and in separate, I think, it will for the column at the compile time so it is displaying error. For now you can do the following

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
SET @sql = ' alter table purchase add stat int'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SET @sql = ' update purchase set stat=0'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

**Note**: Please check the column existence if you would need to call multiple times

Answer (score 0):

When you add any column to existing table then allow null or provide some default value.
And also prevent the DDL command from being executed more then once, otherwise it will throw error on next execution.
And for update its throw error because name column didn't exist while creating the proc. Update statement must as dynamic query.

```
    create procedure [dbo].[abcd1] @tablename sysname
        as
        begin
        declare @query nvarchar(4000)

        declare @name_test varchar(20)  
        set @query = N'select top 10 * from transorg_DW.dbo.'+@tablename
        print @query
        if not exists(select * from sys.columns c join sys.tables t on c.object_id=t.object_id 
                      where t.name='test_exam' and c.name='name')
         begin
             --new column added must be as null value or default value
             alter table test_exam 
             add name varchar(20) null;

         end
       declare @query1 nvarchar(4000)
        set @query1='update test_exam set name=''shyam'' where id=1';
        exec (@query1)
        exec sp_executesql 
        end
```

Enjoy hope this will help.

Comment: still the error is same 'invalid column name 'name' '.  update statement is not working.